# Detect background color of the tables with only "quick stylies" applied

Tags: excel, vba

I have tables `Table32` and `Table28`.

Both were first created and then each of them was selected and then a quick style was selected for each of them from the Excel ribbon's link *"Table design / Quick styles"*.

`Table32` was assigned a *"quick style"* by the name `White, Table Style Medium 4` and `Table28` was assigned a *"quick style"* by the name `Green, Table Style Medium 7`.

Now they look like this:

[image]

Now I want to write a VBA code which does something regarding of the table's color.

So I found out that I can detect `TableStyle` like this:

```
Debug.Print Sheet20.ListObjects("Table32").TableStyle
TableStyleMedium4
Debug.Print Sheet20.ListObjects("Table28").TableStyle
TableStyleMedium7
```

But I simply can't detect the color! I get the same value for both tables!?

```
Debug.Print Sheet20.ListObjects("Table32").HeaderRowRange.Interior.Color
 16777215 
Debug.Print Sheet20.ListObjects("Table28").HeaderRowRange.Interior.Color
 16777215
```

I was expecting to get `White` and `Green` according to the chosen *"quick styles"* `White, Table Style Medium 4` and `Green, Table Style Medium 7` that I selected from the ribbon...

Comment: The table style is independent of the `Range.Interior.Color`.

Comment: @BigBen I know, but table style under the *"quick styles"* is labeled `White, Table Style Medium 4` which means that it has `White` color and that table style is `TableStyleMedium4`. I know how to detect the table style, but I don't know how to detect that `White` color...

Comment: Hmm to me that seems like `White` is still "part" of the table style in some way.

Answer (score 1):

You have to access the `Tablestyle`-object to retrieve the color.

```vb
Sub testListobjectTableStyle()

Dim arrLo(1) As ListObject
Set arrLo(0) = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
Set arrLo(1) = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(2)

Dim i As Long, ts As TableStyle
For i = 0 To 1
    Debug.Print arrLo(i).TableStyle

    Set ts = ThisWorkbook.TableStyles(arrLo(i).TableStyle)
    Debug.Print "style color:", ts.TableStyleElements(xlHeaderRow).Interior.Color
    Debug.Print "applied color:", arrLo(i).HeaderRowRange.Interior.Color
Next

End Sub
```

`HeaderRowRange.Interior.Color` will return `vbWhite`=16777215, if nothing was changed or will return the color the user applied manually to the individual header.

So you could use this function to return the "visible" color:

```vb
Public Function getHeaderRowRangeInteriorColor(lo As ListObject) As Long
With lo
    If .HeaderRowRange.Interior.Color <> vbWhite Then
        getHeaderRowRangeInteriorColor = .HeaderRowRange.Interior.Color
    Else
        Dim ts As TableStyle
        Set ts = ThisWorkbook.TableStyles(.TableStyle)
        getHeaderRowRangeInteriorColor = ts.TableStyleElements(xlHeaderRow).Interior.Color
    End If
End With
End Function
```